# Dynamic scaling of groups within a layer

Tags: javascript, expression, after-effects

I've got a logo made up of several hundred dots that I want to scale in from left to right. I've found a tutorial on how to do just that using the tint of a gradient background, but each of my separate dots in the logo are all scaling together using the layer centre point. I need to target the individual centre points of each dot instead. The original code is this, which would work fine if each dot was on a separate layer:

```
sourceLayer = thisComp.layer("Gradient");
sampleSize = [1,1];
samplePoint = transform.position;
colour= sourceLayer.sampleImage(samplePoint,sampleSize);
x=colour[0]*100;
[x,x]
```

I've tried this code on each of the groups inside the layer which isn't causing code warnings, but also isn't returning the centre point of the individual dots and getting me the color value I'm after to adjust the scale of the dots:

```
sourceLayer = thisComp.layer("Gradient");
sampleSize = [1,1];
samplePoint = thisProperty.propertyGroup(1).propertyGroup(1).transform.position;
colour= sourceLayer.sampleImage(samplePoint,sampleSize);
x=colour[0]*100;
[x,x]
```

Any help on what's wrong with my syntax would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the logo to shapes with [ExplodeShapeLayers](https://aescripts.com/explode-shape-layers/) which has a trial version for 7 days.
Alternatively you could try to get the effect by using [Cloners and Effectors](https://aescripts.com/cloners-plus-effectors/) which also has a 7 day trial

Let me know how you solved it